# Library for caching references when fetching data from Database

Tags: java, database, multithreading, caching

This sounds like a simple question but I'm currently developing a server application that should be able to serve many clients at the same time.

Is there any pattern or -even better- a library that is capable of loading objects on demand from database and asynchronously post them to multiple remote calls.

I was thinking of hibernate. But since I'Ve just heard of it I'm not sure if that is what I need.

The problem that I have is that it would require tons of locks, queues and Runnables to build a threadsafe cache for objects build from database.

Comment: Go for [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) - it ticks all the boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***DO NOT REINVENT THE WHEEL!***

JPA and Hibernate are both wonderful solutions for Object to Relational Database mapping.

Any JPA provider, and Hibernate, will effectively cache objects, even in multi-threaded environments.

If this is your first project working with ORM, take the time to learn it... you will never regret it.